# Проблема с Dagger 2

Tags: android, android-sdk

Делаю тестовый проект с использованием `Dagger2`. 
Попадаю на ошибку

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSetMultimap$Builder.putAll(Ljava/lang/Iterable;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableSetMultimap$Builder;

Не могу понять в чем дело. Поиски решения пока что не увенчались успехом.

Вот код проекта:

**App:**

```
public class App extends Application {
private static AppComponent component;
public static AppComponent getComponent() {
    return component;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    component = buildComponent();
}
protected AppComponent buildComponent() {
    return DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .build();
}
}
```

**AppComponent:**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {NetWorkApiModule.class})
 public interface AppComponent {
 void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}
```

**NetWorkApiModule:**

```
@Module
public class NetWorkApiModule {

@Provides
@Singleton
public NetWorkApi getNetwork(){
    return new NetWorkApi();
}
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Inject NetWorkApi mNetWorkApi;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    App.getComponent().inject(this);
    boolean injected = mNetWorkApi != null;
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(String.valueOf(injected));
}
}
```

Comment: [Пишут](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=206407), что можно откатиться на dagger 2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скопировал полностью ваш код, все работает.
В gradle project

```
 // Assists in working with annotation processors for Android Studio.
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
```

в gradle app

```
// Dagger 2 and Compiler
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.1'
apt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.1"

//Needed for @Generated annotation (missing in Android API jar)
// No longer needed in dagger >= 2.1-SNAPSHOT (github.com/google/dagger/issues/95)
compile 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'

// Assists in working with annotation processors for Android Studio.
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. У меня было provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28' поставил compile 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0' и все заработало.